# I want to make an excel formula to add days to specific date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet for my coworkers.

This sheet has a cell with a `TODAY()` function.

I have another Column that calculate when the person come to work - the cell with a `TODAY()` function.

This Column enable me to know how many days that the person stays on site and it works with no problem.

But the problem comes when I hope to add new feature that calculate the vacation for any coworker.

I have created a column with name (how many Days of vacation)
and make the column that has a date when the person come to work = TODAY() cell + (how many Days of vacation) so it calculates when the person will come correctly but unfortunately it changes daily because of TODAY()

Any help doesn't make this to change.

I expect to calculate when the person come and how many days stay in work in this excel sheet.

Comment: Please share sample data and (at least one) example with that data.

Answer (score 0):

You may be over complicating it as it's a matter of simple addition. In this case you can have the exact date entered manually in one column and the number of vacation days in another, e.g. =A1+B1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).